# Consider the following system of equations:

Tags: linear-algebra

ax+by=k,
cx+dy=l,
ex+fy=m

Disscuss the relative positions of the above three lines when
(i) the system has no solution.
(ii) the system has exactly one solution.
(iii) the system has infitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

When a system of linear equations does not have a solution, the system is called inconsistent. In this case, the three lines do not intersect.

When a general system of linear equations has exactly one solution, it is called consistent and independent. In this case, each line in the system intersects at exactly one point; thus, the system is also linearly independent.

Finally, when a system of linear equations has infinitely many solutions, it is called consistent and dependent. So, a system with this property consists of collinear lines—each line shares at least one point and they all point in the same direction. Collinearity means that each line in a consistent and dependent system can be expressed as a scalar multiple of each other making them linearly dependent by definition.